# All Buttons Same Size, Center Text(Android)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have 6 buttons. The XML is as follows for each one. How to go about changing them so that the button text is centered and the they are all the same size?

I assumed that setting the size would do the trick?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>


<Button 
android:id="@+id/Button1" 
android.layout_height="100px"
android.layout_width="60px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="BUTTON1"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

in  button attributes.
Button width can be changed by android:padding attribute in LinearLayout
Example:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:paddingLeft="10px"
 android:paddingRight="10px"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >


 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/Button1" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:text="BUTTON1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use fill_parent for all child height and layout_weight="1", hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the text center of the button use the: 
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" attribute.

For the size use the  android:layout_height="100px" and  android:layout_width="60px" attributes.

This is the full xml layout of the button:

```
     <Button 
 android:id="@+id/button" 
 android:layout_height="100px" 
 android:layout_width="60px"
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 android:text="Your text!"/>
```